# Vue JS method not causing timer to count down

Tags: vue.js

Hi I am trying to build a timer that will count down from e.g. 6 seconds to 0.

```
var timerArea = Vue.component('timer-area', {
data: function () {
    return ({
        timeValue: 6,
        showTimer: true
    });
},
methods: {
    countdownTimer: function () {
        // Set the date we're counting down to
        var downloadTimer = setInterval(function () {
            this.timeValue--;
            if (this.timeValue <= 0) {
                clearInterval(downloadTimer);
                this.showTimer = false;
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
},
ready() {
    this.countdownTimer();
},
template: `<div v-if="this.showTimer" id="timerCountdownPlaceholder" class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" style="height: 600px">
    <div class="text-center justify-content-center container">
        <h1 id="timerCountdown" class="display-3">{{ this.timeValue }}</h1>
    </div>
</div>`,
```

})

The number 6 is diplayed but it is not updated when it counts down and the

```
if (this.timeValue <= 0) {
            clearInterval(downloadTimer);
            this.showTimer = false;
        }
```

this.timevalue gives off NaN.

Anyone know whats going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a scoping issue, `this` inside a callback refers to the execution context of the callback, not the Vue instance, you should either use an arrow function (which do not create their own `this`), or if using ES5, bind `this` to the callback:

```
countdownTimer: function () {
    // Set the date we're counting down to
    var downloadTimer = setInterval(() => {
        this.timeValue--;
        if (this.timeValue <= 0) {
            clearInterval(downloadTimer);
            this.showTimer = false;
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Or in ES5:

```
countdownTimer: function () {
    // Set the date we're counting down to
    var downloadTimer = setInterval(function () {
        this.timeValue--;
        if (this.timeValue <= 0) {
            clearInterval(downloadTimer);
            this.showTimer = false;
        }
    }.bind(this), 1000);
}
```

Comment: This worked a charm, thank you so much! One day i'll get the hang of this Vue thing XD